# Callback para Transições em CSS3

Tags: javascript, css3

Existe alguma função callback em javascript ou jQuery para as transições em objetos feitas em css3?

Comment: CSS não tem callbacks. Se a transição fôr feita em javascript/jQuery isso é possivel. Pode colocar o código em questão e/ou explicar melhor o que pretende fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Via Javascript você pode utilizar o evento `webkitTransitionEnd` para determinar o momento onde uma transição termina. Por exemplo:

```
meuElemento.addEventListener( 
     'webkitTransitionEnd', 
     function( event ) { alert( "A transição terminou." ); }, false );
```

Até onde sei não existe equivalente em CSS3 para este comportamento.